# set tmux/R window background color when using Vim-R

Tags: r, vim, vim-plugin

I'm using MacVim and Vim-R to interactively edit and run R code. Everything seems to be working fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the background color in the tmux window that R runs in.

To be precise: I open up a .r file with MacVim. Then I type _rf, which causes XQuartz to start up, and a window with the title 'tmux' to open up with R running inside of it. When I highlight lines of code and send them to R from MacVim, everything seems to work fine. But the default background color of the tmux window is white, which makes the nicely colored output text hard to read.

How can I change the background color of the tmux window to something darker?

Comment: What terminal emulator does tmux open up in? That's where you need to set the background color.

Comment: I'm using xterm and XQuartz; and thanks! You're right; following @romainl's answer below, I had to set the color scheme for xterm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this part of the doc](https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin/blob/aade929242a5099b9dd82822e4817ba8674fffcb/doc/r-plugin.txt#L1033) to force your plugin to use the right terminal emulator.

If you don't want to do that (I think that you should), you can configure the appearance of xterm in the `~/.Xresources` file. [This guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/x_resources#Sample_usage) gives you useful examples.

Comment: Thanks! I created a file called ~/.Xresources and added the colors in the example you linked to; everything now works fine. It doesn't seem to matter whether or not I force the plugin to use xterm, but maybe that will make the setup more robust.